# Why cant I pass parameter into an anonymous function inside addEventListener, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a function name edit(index). index is the id number of  h1 tag elements. Whenever i click the edit button (which is has id index) then the input text appear for me to adding some text therefor i can submit another button.

```
function saveChange(index) {    
    if(editName.value != "") {
        productList[index] = editName.value;   
    }    
    spoiler.style.display = 'none'; 
}

//and here i call the event
function edit(index) {    
    spoiler.style.display = "block";    
    document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',saveChange(index)); 
}
```

how can i pass the index parameter?

Comment: Put it inside another? `() => saveChange(index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function if you want to pass parameters in `addEventListener`. Use this code instead:

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', () => saveChange(index));
```

This is because if you add the `saveChange(index)` into `addEventListener` by itself, it will actually *execute* the function rather than saving it for use in the event listener. This is the same reason you have to use function references/anonymous functions inside `setInterval` and `setTimeout` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739674/) for some more information on this).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function inside of an anonymous function.

Change

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',saveChange(index));
```

To

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function(){saveChange(index)});
```

**Demo:**

```js
function saveChange(index) { 
  console.log("save: "+index);
  //if(editName.value != "") {
    //productList[index] = editName.value;   
  //}    
  //spoiler.style.display = 'none'; 
}

//and here i call the event
function edit(index) {    
  //spoiler.style.display = "block";    
  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function(){saveChange(index)}); 
}

edit(10)
```

```html
<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me. Inside the function saveChange(index), I add this code:  [console.log("save:"+index);] and i call edit(10) function. It shows save: undefined when i click the button to add the event

Comment: @ThịnhNguyễnVăn, since there is no relevant HTML in your question, it is difficult to tell what the actual issue is. Though I have added an executable code snippet showing that how the function is called by passing the parameter........thanks

Comment: yep; anyway I solved the problem, thanks you

Comment: @ThịnhNguyễnVăn, if the answer helps then you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green*.....thanks